# Отображение данных для аутентифицированных пользователей

Tags: python-3.x, django

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы часть функций (кнопки и ссылки) были недоступны неавторизованным пользователям. То есть если пользователь неавторизован, то видны не все кнопки и часть ссылок недоступна, а для вошедшего пользователя недоступны кнопки и, соответственно, ссылки авторизации и регистрации . Как это можно выполнить?
Работаю с самой последней версией django через стандартный UserCreationForm
Может есть какие-то гайды или кто-то сталкивался с необходимостью сделать это? В теории можно и не через UserCreationForm, но я и с ним промучился много, поэтому не знаю, смогу ли создать форму, используя другой модуль

Comment: Может, просто в шаблонах с помощью условия `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример шаблона:

```
  {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
#если пользователь вошел в систему он видит:
      <a href="{% url 'путь' %}">Настройки</a>
      <a href="{% url 'путь' %}">Выход</a>
  {% else %}
#неавторизованный пользователь видит:
      <a  href="{% url 'путь' %}">Вход</a>
      <a  href="{% url 'путь' %}">Регистрация</a>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Все работает, кнопки скрываются, но! По ссылке то все равно можно перейти. Нет ли какого-то контроля доступа для (не)авторизованных пользователей?

Comment: В самой функции во views сделай, чтобы не простой редирект на твою страницу был, а с условием: `if request.user.is_staff:
    return redirect('quests:approvals')` - если пользователь имеет права администратора и `if request.user.is_authenticated():
    return redirect('quests:quests')` - если пользователь просто авторизован